# How to maintain the a single log file for the multiple exceptions

Tags: java, exception

I have written a program in java which implements some task. I have handled the exception at many places in the program.

My program will daily executes once in a day. I want to maintain a log file in which I want to write the exception if any with the date and time. (At what date and time it gets arise in the program if the program get runs multiple times in the day.)

What should I do for maintaining the single log file? Also I want to save my file with the name like : Log_2012-04-06_0600PM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using any logging framework like [logback](/questions/tagged/logback) or [log4j](/questions/tagged/log4j)? They provide everything you need. Logging exception is as simple as:

```
catch(Exception e) {
  log.error("Opps!", e)
  //...
}
```

The framework will add any [diagnostic information](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#ClassicPatternLayout) you want, including timestamp, current thread name, class name, etc.

The requirement of adding timestamp to file name is also easily achievable, check out [`RollingFileAppender`](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender). It will create new log file based on chosen policy, typically every day/hour or when the file grows too large.

Answer (score 2):

[log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) is your answer.

log4j does everything and is used by everyone.  It supports, among other things, rotation of log files on [customised schedules](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html)
with [custom filename formats](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html#setDatePattern%28java.lang.String%29).  It can be configured from inside the application or via an external properties file.

Answer (score 1):

Log all caught exceptions with ERROR or higher log level, then create a separate appender with ERROR level, and attach it to the root category so that it receives all log messages.

To get the desired filename, use a rolling file appender. This can be configured to roll daily, and append the date to the og file name. The configuration of this is framework dependent. If you haven't chosen a logging framework yet, I recommend Log4J or LogBack.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above posts.  Use Log4J.  You can use a single or multiple log files, rolling files, and save the file in any format you would like.